# Wordpress plugin problem with encoding

Tags: encoding

Ok I made wordpress contact form plugin. Basiclly in form i have dropdown list of states loaded from database. In db i have country name in Romanian. For example

```
FederaÅ£ia RusÄƒ 
Polinezia francezÄƒ 
Jamahiriya ArabÄƒ LibianÄƒ 
Iran, Republica IslamicÄƒ
```

Dispite when i click page source in my header i have UTF 8, but countries name are loaded in row format, other countries are loaded correctlly. For example

```
Rom&#226;nia
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncommented constant db `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8')` in config.php file